# Is it possible to calculate the impact points in this problem?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I am a 18 years old foreign guy with no higher level math education, so I apologize for potentially bad grammar in my question, I hope you will understand what I'm saying nontheless. So I've been trying to solve this self-made problem which is as follows:

Imagine the two-dimensional space on the positive sides of the coordinate plane. You are given the coordinates of two points that can be anywhere between $0$ and infinity. Lets call them $A$ and $B$.
As an example, lets say $A$ is at $(6.5, 10.7)$ and $B$ is at $(8.7, 5.6)$. Imagine a ray of light travelling from point $A$ to point $B$, reflecting off both the $X$ and $Y$ axis.
The question is: Is it possible to calculate the impact points on the $X$ and $Y$ axis, while only knowing the values $A$ and $B$? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ5Dc.jpg) is an image to help you understand what I mean.
In this image I drew a quick and bad approximation of the answer for that example, the solution seems to be approximately $X=4$ and $Y=4$.

So, since there is only one right answer for each pair of points, I'd assume an unique formula exists for calculating it. Does such a formula exist? Is this an existing problem? Is it even possible in any way except from trial and error to solve this? Apart from calculations, I've also tried to geometrically find some methods, but haven't had any luck.

Extra notes:
I managed to solve a simplified version of this problem, which is having just one reflection on just one axis.

I will gladly explain better if needed, hopefully someone will enlighten me about this, it's been on my mind for days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection of $B = (8.7, 5.6)$ across both $x$ and $y$ axes (in either order) produces $B' = (-8.7, -5.6)$.  A ray of light that goes from $A$ to $B$, reflecting off each axis, corresponds to a straight line from $A$ to $B'$.
This straight line will intersect both axes.  The first hitting point is where it intersects one axis (with $x > 0$ or $y > 0$).  The second hitting point is the reflection across that axis of where it intersects the other axis.

In your example, the line from $A$ to $B'$ can be given the parametric form
$[6.5 + t (-8.7 - 6.5), 10.7 + t (-5.6 - 10.7)] = [-15.2 t+6.5, -16.3 t+10.7]$, where $t=0$ corresponds to $A$ and $t=1$ to $B'$.
This intersects the $y$ axis when $-15.2 t+6.5 = 0$, so $t \approx .4276315789$, corresponding to  the point $[0, 3.729605264]$.
It intersects the $x$ axis when $-16.3 t + 10.7 = 0$, so $t \approx
.6564417178$, corresponding to the point $[-3.477914111, 0]$.  Thus the
hit points are (first) $[0,3.729605264]$ on the $y$ axis and (second) $[3.477914111, 0]$ on the $x$ axis.

[image]

Comment: I see, I was trying way too complex stuff when the answer was this simple. Thanks.